# Subclipse svn not showing conflicts

Tags: eclipse, svn, subclipse

I just set up an SVN repository, and when either me or my pair coder synchronize, we never ever see conflicts.  Conflicts mode is always empty, and whenever we upload or download files, they are simply overwritten.  Anyone else run into this issue?

Comment: Are you sure that the files are being overwritten not merged?

Answer (score 0):

Subclipse is just a GUI layer on top of the Subversion API.  All of the work during an update/commit etc is carried about the same Subversion libraries that the Subversion command line uses.  When you do an update, Subversion will automatically merge changes in files and only creates a conflict when it cannot do this.  In Eclipse if you open the Console view and show the SVN Console page you will see the output from the API. During an update, you should see an entry like this:

U  folder/filename.ext

The U indicates that the file was 'U'pdated.  If there is a conflict you will see a 'C'.  Subclipse will also decorate the file with a conflict decorator.

The Synchronize view is an Eclipse feature.  It shows files as either Incoming or Outgoing.  A Conflict in the Synchronize view simply means that the same file has both Incoming and Outgoing changes.  The Synchronize view does not know if Subversion will be able to auto-merge the changes or create a conflict.